# Cannot find module 'ionic-angular' Migrating Ionic 3 to Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

I am migrating a PWA written in Ionic 3 to Ionic 4 framework, 'ionic-angular' works  perfectly in Ionic 3. but in case of Ionic 4 its throwing compile error.

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ionic-angular'

please help

Comment: ionic-angular not longer exists in ionic4

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Ezlo, figured out how to use it,

Ionic 4 uses '@ionic/angular'